# how to change column flex?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs4

I cannot flex columns, i have a grid, I used all methods but they don't work

```
        var cols = [];
        cols.push(Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
            text: 'Valuta from', flex:1, columns: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { text: 'Valuta', dataIndex: 'ratesValutaFromName', flex:2 }),
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { text: 'Amount', dataIndex: 'ratesValutaFromAmount', flex:2 })
            ],

        }));

        cols.push(Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
            text: 'Valuta To', flex:1, columns: [

                Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { text: 'Valuta', dataIndex: 'ratesValutaToName',  flex:2 }),
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { text: 'Amount', dataIndex: 'ratesValutaToAmount', flex:2  })
            ],


        }));` and flex dont't work
```

Comment: Are you asking us a question about Adobe/Apache Flex, the UI Framework?  Or is this a question about extJS?  I'm guessing the latter so I removed the Flex tag.

Comment: What are you expecting this to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: Why so many Ext.create()? Just use the configuration syntax: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-columns

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need do something like this.

```
var myColumns = new Array({
                           text      : 'field One',
                           dataIndex : 'fieldOne',
                           flex      : 1
                        },
                        {
                           text      : 'Field Two',
                           dataIndex : 'fieldTwo',
                           flex      : 2
                        },
                        {
                           text      : 'Field Three',
                           dataIndex : 'fieldThree',
                           flex      : 3
                        }
    ),
    grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
        title : 'Testing',
        width : 400,
        height : 400,
        columns : myColumns,
        store : yourStore,
        renderTo : Ext.getBody()
        //Or add this grid to another component like
        // a tab panel
    });
```

This is an example. You can see fieldOne, fieldTwo and fieldThree the flex property work with the coefficient between all flex properties in different columns.

- fieldOne is more small that fieldTwo.
- fieldTwo is more small that fieldThree.
- fieldThree is more bigger that fieldOne and fieldTwo.